# Cannot disable night light

Tags: night-light

I have fresh installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. After installation, I noticed that the colors on my monitor changed. I look in the Night Light settings, it's disabled by default, when I turn it on, nothing changes. If I use the slider to set the color temperature to warm or less warm, it will change. however, if I turn off the night color feature, it won't go back to normal color, but just stay as it is. How to return colors to normal state ?